# Django rest framework model is not visible in admin site

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a simple DRF API and I can't seem to access one of my many models from the admin site, although I can access some models from the same Application, please help!

project/app/models.py looks something like this:

```py
class ImportantModel(models.Model):
   name = # character field
   relation1 = # foreign key
   relation2 = # foreign key
   ...

class Contact(models.Model):
   information = # character field
   ...
```

The problem is I can see the `Contact` model(and multiple other models) from the admin site(`http://localhost:8000/admin/`) but `ImportantModel` is not showing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you register it in admin.py (admin.site.register(ImportantModel))?

Comment: I have, but it just won't show.

Comment: Try running python manage.py syncdb.

Comment: And restart you server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your model in admin.py file.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was in same problem because the problem is I registered my models in admin.py file but in a wrong way

wrong way:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article
from .models import User

# Register your models here.
admin.register(Article)
admin.register(User)
```

And the right way is

right way:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article
from .models import User

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Article)
admin.site.register(User)
```